# Strange Display Problem

Tags: 22.04, intel-graphics, display-resolution, nvidia-geforce

Ubuntu 22.04.4, Wayland.

Grpahics:
Intel Driver i915, model 4693
NVIDIA model GK208B[GeForce GT 730], UMD Version NVIDIA 470.199.02

I have five monitors plugged into these two graphics cards:
Two are plugged into the Intel card with HDMI connectors.
Three are plugged into the NVIDIA card: Two with DVI-D connectors, and one with a VGA connector.

Here is a summary of my problematic situation:

-When I unplug the two monitors that use the intel graphics receptacles (two HDMI), the remaining three monitors using the nvidia graphics card (two DVID-D and one VGA) will allow me to use all the listed resolutions for each of those three monitors in the Ubuntu >> Settings >> Display screen.

-However, when I plug those two monitors into the two intel graphics receptacles and keep the other three monitors plugged into the nvidia graphics card, then I get this situation:

```
-Only one of the monitors plugged into the intel card (HDMI), and only one of the monitors plugged into the nvidia card (DVI-D) will allow me to selected all listed resolutions.

-The other three monitors - one plugged into the intel card (HDMI), and two plugged into the nvidia card (VGA and DVID-D) - will refuse to use any resolution higher than 1024 X 768
```

I want all five monitors to allow all capable resolutions when all five monitors are plugged in.

Why am I having this problem? How do I fix this?

Comment: for testing you should log out and configure your session as X11 (instead of Wayland) - then login again. Maybe Wayland can't cope with your config

Comment: Thanks much.  Your suggestion made me realize that somehow my login was now defaulting to an X11 session instead of the Wayland session I'd been using these past couple years.  Once I corrected that, all these problems went away.

Answer (score 0):

I had unknowingly - somehow - changed to using an X11 session instead of Wayland, which is what I had always been using, and thought I still was using.  Changing that back to Wayland solved these problems.